# Explicit triangulation of a genus 3 surface $X^4+Y^4+Z^4=0$

Tags: riemann-surfaces, geometric-topology, triangulation

I tried to describe the Riemann surface $X^4+Y^4+Z^4=0$ as a surface in real 3-dimensional space (without self-intersection) with triangulation.

I picked $12$ points on the surface:
$P_{a} = [0:1:\zeta^a], Q_{a}= [\zeta^{a}:0:1], R_{a} = [1:\zeta^a:0]$,
where $a \in \{1,3,5,7\}, \zeta = (1+i)/\sqrt2$.

I join $P_a$ $Q_b$ by the parametlized curve:
$[X:Y:Z] = [ζ^b  t: ζ^{-a} \sqrt[4] {1-t^4}:1]$.
Similarly I join $Q_aR_B$ and $R_aP_b$.

Then I found following triangles are contractible:
$\triangle P_1Q_1R_5,
\triangle P_1Q_1R_7,
\triangle P_1Q_3R_3,
\triangle P_1Q_3R_5,
\triangle P_1Q_5R_1,
\triangle P_1Q_5R_3,
\triangle P_1Q_7R_1,
\triangle P_1Q_7R_7$
$\triangle P_3Q_1R_3,
\triangle P_3Q_1R_5,
\triangle P_3Q_3R_1,
\triangle P_3Q_3R_3,
\triangle P_3Q_5R_1,
\triangle P_3Q_5R_7,
\triangle P_3Q_7R_5,
\triangle P_3Q_7R_7$
$\triangle P_5Q_1R_1,
\triangle P_5Q_1R_3,
\triangle P_5Q_3R_1,
\triangle P_5Q_3R_7,
\triangle P_5Q_5R_5,
\triangle P_5Q_5R_7,
\triangle P_5Q_7R_3,
\triangle P_5Q_7R_5$
$\triangle P_7Q_1R_1,
\triangle P_7Q_1R_7,
\triangle P_7Q_3R_5,
\triangle P_7Q_3R_7,
\triangle P_7Q_5R_3,
\triangle P_7Q_5R_5,
\triangle P_7Q_7R_1,
\triangle P_7Q_7R_3$
(I found this by integrating $3$ holomorphic differentials which I previously described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3859151/jacobian-variety-of-fermat-quartic-x4y4z4-0-as-3-torus))

Thus I have $12$ points and $48$ edges, and $32$ triangles on the surface. (The Euler characteristic shows that this is a genus 3 surface.)

So I tried to choose $12$ points on a sphere with $3$ handles, and draw $48$ edges ($8$ edges for each point) to triangulate, satisfying the relations above. But it was really difficult and I couldn't succeed. Is this actually possible (and can you draw it)?

What I tried else:
I considered 4 cones with:
Apex:$P_1$, 8-edged bottom $Q_1R_5Q_3R_3Q_5R_1Q_7R_7Q_1$ 
Apex:$P_3$, 8-edged bottom $Q_1R_3Q_3R_1Q_5R_7Q_7R_5Q_1$ 
<s>Apex:P_5, 8-edged bottom Q_1R_1Q_7R_5Q_5R_7Q_3R_7Q_1</s> 

Apex:$P_5$, 8-edged bottom $Q_1R_1Q_3R_7Q_5R_5Q_7R_3Q_1$ 
<s>Apex:P_7, 8-edged bottom Q_1R_1Q_3R_5Q_5R_3Q_7R_3Q_1</s> 

Apex:$P_7$, 8-edged bottom $Q_1R_1Q_7R_3Q_5R_5Q_3R_7Q_1$ 
Then patch together with the blue edges or pink edges respectively.
But it seems to me that it is not possible in 3-dimensional space without self-intersection (but I am not sure).

**EDIT**
I tried again with more symmetric shape and succeeded so I have posted it as an answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that instead of considering the cone with 8 edges, I can just use the area formed by the edges, because they are homeomorphism.
I used more symmetric 4 shapes each has $8$ points and $8$ edges with the relation described in the question. The shapes are shown in the attached pictures.

I painted the inside (bottom side) by glay and the outside (top side) by light blue.
The order to patch them is:
$P_1\to P_7\to P_5\to P_3$  in the upper area containing $Q_1,R_1,Q_5,R_5$,
$P_5\to P_3\to P_1\to P_7$ in the lower area containing $Q_3,R_3,Q_7,R_7$,
in the direction from top to bottom.

At first I couldn't image that it can be realized in 3-dimensional space so I made a model by paper. I observed it is actually a surface with genus 3.

[image]

[image]